# How to make a specific div move with arrow keys (specified by button clicked)

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, position, keycode

I have 2 divs (#1 and #2) and two buttons. When a button is clicked, it should select a div to move and when the arrow keys are pressed, this div should move. The other should remain in its place. If the other button is clicked, the div that had previously moved should remain in its new position and the newly selected div should move along with the arrow keys.

```
.counter {
                border-radius:50%;
                width:20px;
                height:20px;
                position:absolute;
                transition:top linear 0.6s, left linear 0.6s;
                font-size:20px;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
                padding:20px;
                top: 525px;
                left: 60px;
                background-color:red;
            }
```

```
<button onclick="one">Move One</button>
           <button onclick="two">Move Two</button>
           <div class="counter" id="1" >1</div>
           <div class="counter" id="2">2</div>
```

```
 var go = "1"
               function one() {
                   go = "1"
               }
               function two() {
                   go = "2"
               }
```

```
document.onkeydown = detectKey;
        function detectKey(e) {
    
        var posLeft = document.getElementById('').offsetLeft
        var posTop = document.getElementById('').offsetTop
        
            if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                if (go === "1") {
        document.getElementById('1').style.left  = (posLeft+150)+"px"
        }  
            if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        document.getElementById('1').style.top  = (posTop-150)+"px"
        }
            }
            
            if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                if (go === "2") {
        document.getElementById('2').style.left  = (posLeft+150)+"px"
        }  
            if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        document.getElementById('2').style.top  = (posTop-150)+"px"
        }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a homework? Is this a pseudo-code? You can't create functions that start with a digit... Why are you making two `if` statements the same but just changing the id? Please expand with comments on your code or add more information, as it's hard to understand what you need :)

Comment: Why not simply make them `draggable` - [How to create draggable elements](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp)

Comment: @ATD I still need to make sure one cannot be moved while the other can be moved, as this is for a board game in which the players take turns. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @DadiBit I have the two if statements bc I am trying to make a div move with the arrow keys, depending on which div is selected via the buttons. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: I haven't done that myself.  The principle should be related to the linked page's `dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));` line (very top of the "Example" section).  The code will only run for the element specified in the `dragElement()` function call.  As long as you know which element may be dragged, you only call the function for that element.  And, therefore, if they try to drag another element, you simply don't call the function.

Comment: You're calling `getElementById()` and passing an empty string. That seems that it's likely to not work.

Comment: @FranciscaRiosDurkin you should implement a global variable that contains the current player and that switches every round (possible values are 1 and 2). Based on the current player that's playing, you will move the div with the id of the player that should move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I have edited the values a bit, but you can easily change them back.

```js
const buttonOne = document.getElementById('button-one');
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById('button-two');

const elementOne = document.getElementById('one');
const elementTwo = document.getElementById('two');

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', clickOnButtonOne);
buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', clickOnButtonTwo);

let selectedElement = null;

function clickOnButtonOne() {
  selectedElement = elementOne;
}

function clickOnButtonTwo() {
  selectedElement = elementTwo;
}

document.onkeydown = detectKey;

function detectKey(e) {
  if (selectedElement) {
    if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      var posLeft = selectedElement.offsetLeft
      selectedElement.style.left = (posLeft + 50) + "px"
    }
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
      var posTop = selectedElement.offsetTop
      selectedElement.style.top = (posTop - 50) + "px"
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.counter {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top linear 0.6s, left linear 0.6s;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 500px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button-one" onclick="one">Move One</button>
<button id="button-two" onclick="two">Move Two</button>

<div class="counter" id="one">1</div>
<div class="counter" id="two">2</div>
```